# how to check whether a field has a value in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How can I check whether there is a value set for a particular field in a table ?

Thank You

Comment: Nimo - do you mean how do you find whether there is a corresponding look-up table for a particular column, or whether a particular column contains any value or not? Senthil is getting downvoted but I've a feeling he's probably closest to what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

.... WHERE field IS NOT NULL ....

Answer (score 1):

We can run a query checking on NOT NULL in the WHERE clause.  I'm using count for convenience.

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  where comm is not null
  4  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

SQL>
```

So that's four rows where COMM has a value set.

If we want to test for the presence of a value in the projection, then we can use `CASE()`, `DECODE()` or one of Oracle's [NULL-related functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#i888936).  For instance, this statement wraps a call to `[NVL2()][2]` in a `SUM()` to count how many instances of COMM are NULL and NOT NULL in the same query.

```
SQL> select sum(nvl2(comm, 1, 0)) as notnull_cnt
  2         , sum(nvl2(comm, 0, 1)) as null_cnt
  3  from emp
  4  /

NOTNULL_CNT   NULL_CNT
----------- ----------
          4         16

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query,

select * from table_name where column_name='field value';

Comment: If the values are returned means then there were some values set..if nothing returned means..then value is not set..In this thought I posted.What is wrong in it?

Comment: There's a language issue I think. You're reading it (I think probably correctly) as "is this value part of a defined set of values a value-set. Everyone else is reading it as "has a value been set or not".

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE that_field IS NULL
```

Or replace `IS NULL` with `IS NOT NULL` if you want to select rows where the field has a value.